# How to convert a image dimensions which are directed through model.flow_from_directory?

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build an image classifier using `Keras 2.2.0` and `tensorflow 1.9.0`

I am getting an error of this sort:

```
str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (1, 224, 224) but got array with shape (224, 224, 3)
```

Here is the code:

```
train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=40,
            width_shift_range=0.2,
            height_shift_range=0.2,
            rescale=1./255,
            shear_range=0.2,
            zoom_range=0.2,
            horizontal_flip=True,
            fill_mode='nearest')

validation_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/media/centura/DANISH/mobile backup/moles/train/',class_mode='binary',target_size=(224, 224),batch_size=batch_size)

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory('/media/centura/DANISH/mobile backup/moles/test/',class_mode='binary',target_size=(224, 224),batch_size=batch_size)

#Data Dimensions
img_rows,img_cols=224,224

input_shape1=(1,img_rows,img_cols)

#initialising the model

model=Sequential()

#layer 1
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same',input_shape=input_shape1,data_format="channels_last"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
#model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))


#fully connected first layer

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(500,use_bias=False))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))      


#Fully connected final layer
model.add(Dense(1)) 
model.add(Activation('sigmoid')) 

tensorboard=TensorBoard(log_dir='logs/{}'.format(name))


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
#model.summary()
model.fit_generator(train_generator,epochs=50,validation_data=validation_generator,callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

I believe the error is coming from the `train_generator`. I searched in stack overflow for similar problems. I found certain solutions but it was not working for me. How can I change the dimensions of the image if it is being called from the `.flow_from_directory`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break down the error step-by-step to find out what it is telling us:

> Error when checking input:

So it is related to the input data and input layer of the model.

> expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (1, 224, 224)

If we look at the code for the first convolution layer we see that:

```
Conv2D(..., input_shape=input_shape1, ...)
```

And the value of `input_shape1` as you have defined it is `(1,img_rows,img_cols)` which is `(1, 224, 224)`. But:

> but got array with shape (224, 224, 3)

Which means the images generated by the `train_generator` have a shape of `(224, 224, 3)` (which is correct and expected).

As a result, we see these two shapes, the shape of generated images and the given shape to `input_shape` argument, must be the same. Therefore, you need to modify the value of `input_shape1` as follows:

```
input_shape1=(img_rows, img_cols, 3)
```

which is exactly what a convolution layer expects as its input shape (i.e. `(image_height, image_width, image_channels)`).

Comment: That was exactly the problem. I was confused of the fact,that the keras is expecting a 4D tensor (batch_size,width,height,channels) so i gave it like that.Thank you !